# Accessing Session variables in /ext/mysql extension

Tags: php, php-extension

I have declared a structure that look like

```
 typedef struct
 {
     char* key;
     char* value;
 }kvPair;
```

and in the session structure, i declared a variable as

```
 struct session
 {

    char* id;
    .....  // other session variables
    kvPair* pair;
  }
```

Now in the session_start I have initialised the values for the pair variable and I have to access these values in /ext/mysql extension. A suggestion on how to achieve it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: OK, what are you trying to do? And what has the mysql extension to do with this?

Comment: @Artefacto: Well since hes posted C code im going to guess hes customizing the mysql extension... Sill more explanation would be nice... as well as a tag for the actual language hes working with (i only guessed at C)

Comment: I am trying to control the access to the database based on the user information. Thats a part of my research on securing the server-side-database access. I tried to include the /ext/php_session.h in /ext/mysql.c . Is this the right way to do? or is there a better way of doing things?

Comment: omg, who adviced you to do in this way?

Comment: @zerkms. Are u talking about the scheme or the inclusion of session.h file in /ext/mysql.c?

Comment: i'm talking about the idea of protecting from something with such solution. from whom are you protecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to read data that was saved in the session e.g. through this script:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["key"] = "data";
```

Then yes, you can use the API exposed by the session extension:

```
#include "ext/session/php_session.h"
```

Then you have these functions:

```
void php_session_start(TSRMLS_D); /* analogue to session_start() in userspace */
int php_get_session_var(char *name, size_t namelen, zval ***state_var TSRMLS_DC);
```

Comment: once I use that. I am able to directly access the session structure variables. For example. to access id variable, i just did PS(id) and it worked like charms. Thank you for your suggestions though!

Comment: @Karth Just because you can, doesn't mean you should. The session extension provides an API, *use it*. If you violate the abstractions, your code will stop working when the internal structures you're accessing change in some future version.

Comment: @Karth Well, in the particular case of fetching the current id, doesn't seem to exist any API.